# What does Gradle do with the files, which are located in src/main/resources directory?

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to figure out, what Gradle does with the files, which are located in src/main/resources directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `processResources` task, added by the java plugin to the project, copies them to the `build/resources/main` directory.

The content of this directory is bundled into the jar file created by the jar task that is also added by the java plugin, and the resources can thus be loaded, at runtime, by the ClassLoader.

See the documentation of [the java plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html).

Answer (score 1):

it might do nothing with them, but ignore them - per default (with the Android plugin) that directory is called `res`, only the Java plugin would take the `resources` directory into account (the question does not indicate which plugin is used). otherwise it would run a `processResources` task on them; only `res/raw` is not being processed (copied 1:1).